# Why Gson parses invalid Json string?

Tags: java, json, gson

As per JSON spec, \ in string must be escaped (i.e, \\) otherwise its [invalid JSON](http://jsonlint.com/).
Gson assumes "\apple" is equal to "apple" without raising an Exception. Why does it ?

```
public class MainApp {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "{\"bar\":\"\\apple\"}";
    /*
        str without escaping = 
        {
            "bar" : "\apple"
        }
    */

    Foo foo = new Gson().fromJson(str, Foo.class);
    System.out.println("In Json = " + "\\" + "apple");
    System.out.println("In Pojo = " + foo.getBar());
}

class Foo {
    private String bar;
    //Setter and getters stripped
}
}
```

Output:

```
 In Json = \apple
 In Pojo = apple
```

It happens only with first character and with 'a'. Whats special in it?

Comment: Here's my own hint: https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/IDS55-J.+Understand+how+escape+characters+are+interpreted+when+strings+are+loaded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Gson` simply escapes by default, if this behaviour is not correct for your method simply do:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().disableHtmlEscaping().create();
Foo foo = gson.fromJson(str, Foo.class);
```

Comment: I tried your code, still POJO constructed has `apple` in it.